# Recovering the table wp_usermeta from users

Tags: database, users, login, user-meta

We had an accident and the table wp_usermeta got truncated.

I have the table wp_usermeta from the staging environment I pushed it in but when I try to login with the admin user (id 1 on both of them)

I'm getting this message:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

I'm being able to login but that's shown on the wp-admin home page

Thanks a lot for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` VALUES (NULL, '1', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` VALUES (NULL, '1', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```